# Firebase: arrayUnion causes DocumentReference.update to fail

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building a factory for a document in Firebase that has to be referenced by another document later. The list stores these entries in a reference array.

```
import firebase from 'firebase/firebase';

//...

let listDoc = db.collection('lists').doc(listId)
db.collection('entries').add({ ... })
  .then(entry => {
    listDoc.update({
      entries: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(entry)
    })
  });
```

This fails due to: `FirebaseError: Function DocumentReference.update() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: a custom bI object (found in field entries)`

I thought that perhaps it was getting caught on the reference for some reason, but even if I pass `entry.id` to the `arrayUnion` method, it produces the same error.  I've checked the documentation for arrayUnion and this all seems to be as expected - what am I missing here?

Firebase JS SDK version `7.14.2`

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be solved by changing the import from `firebase/firebase` to `firebase/app` - the type is valid in both, but only `firebase/app` returns the right data structure.